# Use Boost and C++0x dialect for iOS 4.x

Tags: c++, ios, boost, c++11, clang

I have an iOS project that mostly uses C++. It uses Boost 1.47.

I tried to enable the C++0x dialect but I got many compile errors from Boost. The only way I was able to make it work was to also enable libc++, which in turn requires that the deployment target is set to iOS 5.

Is there a way to make Boost and the C++0x dialect compatible with the default libstdc++? Can some Boost #defines fix this? Should I wait for Boost 1.48 or just forget it?

Comment: "*I tried to enable the C++0x dialect but I got many compile errors from Boost.*" Like what? How do you expect to get help if you don't describe the problem?

Comment: Boost 1.48 just came out, will try after it makes its way into Macports and report here.

Answer (score 2):

It works fine with Boost 1.48 if I add "BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES" to the Preprocessor macros setting.

Summary of the configuration: Using iOS SDK 5.0, XCode 4.2.1, target is iOS 4.3, Boost 1.48, the BOOST_NO_VARIADIC_TEMPLATES define, LLVM 3.0, C++ Language dialect set to C++0x, C++ Standard library set to default (libstdc++). Everything including Boost compiles and works and I can use C++11 features in my project.